# find issue: -print works but not -exec /usr/bin/ls -l '{}' \;

Tags: find

Why

```
find . -mtime 1 -print
```

shows two recently modified files but

```
find . -mtime 1  -exec /usr/bin/ls -l '{}' \;
```

or

```
find . -mtime 1  -exec /usr/bin/ls -l {} \;
```

is processed correctly but shows nothing?

Edit: it is now working - all three produce the expected output! Thank you for all suggestions and still don't know what prevent the last two forms of working.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show an exact situation where that happens? Like, what are those files, or how did you create them, etc.

Comment: In particular please show the modified date for those files and include the date/time you ran the commands (`date`)

Comment: I ran all three commands and they all produced an identical list of files. Please provide more details.

Comment: ...and the reason for the suggestion to show details was to help in figuring out what actually happens and why it didn't work. Though roaima's hypothesis of hitting empty directories with `ls` does sound a plausible one.

Answer (score 1):

You've found two empty directories rather than two files. Test this theory by using `ls -ld` instead of `ls -l`, which will list the directory entry rather than its contents:

```
find . -mtime 1 -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

Or if you really only want files,

```
find . -type f -mtime 1 -exec ls -l {} \;
```

Notice that `-mtime 1` matches items last changed a day ago, no more and no less. If you want items modified less than 24 hours ago, you can use `-mtime -1`.

Comment: Shouldn't `ls -l emptydir` show `total 0`? Plain `ls emptydir` would give the empty output, though.

Comment: @ilkkachu mm, yes you're right

Comment: @ilkkachu "shows nothing" in the question _could_ mean it does show "total 0" but no actual files etc.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yeah, that did cross my mind. I would have asked them to provide the whole output, but if it's actually nothing like they said, that request would seem a bit silly. I guess we could, as a general rule, ask people to run something like `echo ---; their command; echo ---` and paste the result to catch things like that, but how well that would fly in practice...

Comment: `-mtime 1` reports the files whose age rounded down to an integer number of days (86400s units) is 1. So those modified between 48h ago and 24h ago. For the ones modified in the last 24h, it's `-mtime 0`. `-mtime -1` also reports those modified in the future.

Comment: Note that `-type f` restricts to *regular* files to the exclusion of any other type of file including directories, but also device, fifo, symlink (whether they point to regular files or not), etc. Use `! -type d` if it's only files of type *directory* you want to exclude.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas indeed, which is why I wrote "_f you really only want files_", which I included because the OP talked about finding files